# Drawing on an image which is inside a QScrollArea?

Tags: image, qt, drawing, qpainter, qscrollarea

If I subclass QLabel and I add a QLabel directly to my QDialog, it works fine. If I add this label inside a ScrollArea, the thing I’m drawing doesn’t show unless I resize the dialog itself. Yes, weird.

I’ve setup compilable example code that indicates what the problem is. What I am trying to do is to select an area of an image with my mouse, by drawing a rectangle on the corresponding area. The images my program is designed to work with can be very large, and thus, I need to have a scroll area so as the dialog to stay at a logical dimension, and not to fill the entire screen (or even multiple workspaces, if we are talking about a linux machine with multiple desktops).

Everything works fine, except that the drawing (selection-rectangle) isn’t visible unless the dialog is resized – manually. I think I have to update something while drawing, but I’m not sure what. Well, here’s the example code: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1151553/

Another issues that I don’t know how to solve (and I want your suggestions there) are (1) when the user is selecting an area, how to set it to automatically scroll when the user actually selects an area by pushing against to a wall of the scroll area (I guess I am understandable here). (2) is there a way to let the user select a rectangle and then, when he left-clicks on a position with holding down the [Shift] button, the bottom right edge of his previous selection to actually go through the point he clicks at?

The [documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/layout.html) indicates that you have to set a Layout somehow somewhere, but I'm not sure how to do this to my occassion.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

about problem (1):

just use of Event. i think mouse Enter Event  or Leave Event is good for that.

and to do that i think you can  use a hidden  rectangular  that fill the whole of the screen. 
and over write the mouse leave Event for that rectangular and tell  in that function , to scroll the page.